# Local time and time zone using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can get the local time and local time zone in a format I like with:

```
split = new Date().toString().split(" ")
# Example
#0 Thu
#1 Feb
#2 18
#3 2016
#4 13:53:42
#5 GMT+0100
#6 (CET)
return split[4].substring(0,5) + " " + split[6].replace("(", "").replace(")", "") + " UTC(" + split[5].slice(split[5].length - 5, split[5].length - 2) + ":" + split[5].substring(split[5].length - 2) + ")"
```

I get:

```
15:42 CET (UTC+01:00)
```

Is there some Angular service / Angular way I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at angular `$filter` and date in documentation:

[angular $filter date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: I know that I can pass a time zone or time offset as parameter, but I don't know that I can get the time zone based on a date.

Comment: @user1283776 is correct. Not only is this barely an answer, it's not a suitable solution. You can't get the time zone from the date filter, plus the time offset is formatted differently, `+1200`, and would require extra work to add the semi-colon.

Comment: maybe `moment` will be useful, look at the doc: [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)